# parse array in html with javascript and render a different span each time

Tags: javascript, html, angular

How can I make this code more general:

```
               <div class="xx" *ngIf="this.message.address">
                    <span class="helper" *ngIf="this.message.address">
                       {{ this.errorMessage.address[0] }} 
                    </span>
                    <span class="helper" *ngIf="this.message.address[1]">
                            {{ this.errorMessage.address[1] }} 
                         </span>
                </div>
```

so that this span is rendered multiple times for each array element:

```
          <span class="xx" *ngIf="this.message.address.forEach(x=> x">
               {{ this.errorMessage.address[x] }} 
            </span>
```

(my attempt above doesn't work by the way)

I could only make it work in the angular component, sth like:

```
this.message.address.forEach(x=> console.log(x))
```

but I'm not sure how to parse an array in html and render a different span in each case, which is what I really need

Comment: why not using `*ngFor` for iteration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is `*ngFor`, which can be used in your HTML to iterate over an array of elements.

```
<div class="xx" *ngFor="let ad of this.message.address">
  <span class="helper" *ngIf="ad">
    {{ ad }} 
  </span>
</div>
```